# Netbird (Selfhosted) Site-to-Site through the Netbird VPN

Tags: site-to-site-vpn, wireguard

I have a question on Site-to-site through the Netbird VPN.

### The setup

#### LAN 1

LAN1 is 192.168.10.0/16 and has two devices on it.

- 192.168.10.1 is debian running netbird and connected to my selfhosted netbird, VPN Address 100.83.10.1
- 192.168.10.2 is debian and has a manual route added for LAN2 going via 192.168.10.1

#### LAN 2

LAN2 is 192.168.20.0/16 and has three devices on it.

- 192.168.20.1 is debian running netbird client and connected to my selfhosted netbird, VPN Address 100.83.20.1.
- 192.168.20.2 is debian and has a manual route added for LAN1 going via 192.168.20.1
- 192.168.20.3 is windows and has a manual route added for LAN1 going via 192.168.20.1

#### Netbird VPN

The Netbird VPN has created a wireguard mesh using the network 100.83.0.0/16
There are no restrictions in the setup, "all" is allowed.

### Testing

- On 192.168.10.1 I can ping 100.83.10.1 and 100.83.20.1
- On 192.168.20.1 I can ping 100.83.10.1 and 100.83.20.1

That's as expected because they are netbird peers

### Adding Network Routes

In Netbird added the Network Route 192.168.10.0/24 and attached to netbird peer 192.168.10.1

Then added the Network Route 192.168.20.0/24 and attached to netbird peer 192.168.20.1
Both Routes have masquerade turned off.

On the devices LAN1 - 192.168.10.2 and LAN2 192.168.20.2 & 20.3 I've added routes to the VPN 100.83.0.0/16 via the respective Netbird peer

At this point it all works....

Devices on LAN1 & LAN2 and ping devices on the 100.83.0.0 network and visa versa

As expected.

#### Adding routes for the LAN's

I then added routes to the devices on LAN1 - 192.168.10.2 for the network 192.168.20.0/24 via Netbird 192.168.10.1

and then added routes to the devices on LAN2 - 192.168.20.2 & 20.3 for the network 192.168.10.0/24 via Netbird 192.168.20.1

However I don't seem to be able to ping from a device on LAN1 to a device on LAN2 going through the VPN. or visa versa

A traceroute shows it going as far as the Netbird peer and then nothing.

On both netbird peers I ensured the iptables was blank and ip_forward was enabled in sysctl.

What am I missing??

Comment: can you tell us for what reason you use 100 instead of 10 subnet?

Comment: @djdomi probably just like Kubernetes does it. It's not the administrator, it's the tool. Example: https://github.com/netbirdio/netbird/blob/v0.26.2/management/server/network.go#L52

Comment: Without knowing the tool, one could do systematic debug at the network layer to see if something is missing there (before figuring out how to tell Netbird to add it). traceroute, multiple tcpdump (one on each supposed involved interface where the packet disappears, both as envelope and payload interface, so 2 or 3 at once per involved system), and a sprinkle of `ip route get from 192.168.10.2 iif someinterface to 192.168.20.2` at multiple points to see where the packet is supposed to continue.